# Listing authorship on a resume

Tags: publications, authorship

I recently published a paper with four other colleagues. The authorship is listed as A*, B*, C*, D, E, where * represents "these authors have contributed equally to this work." I am B*. Do I list "Co-authored a paper published..." or "First co-authored a paper published..."?

Comment: What's this resume for?  On a typical academic CV, you simply have a section for "Publications" and list the full citation for each one; you don't have introductory wording like "co-authored a paper".  If it's a resume for use in business outside academia, http://workplace.stackexchange.com may have better expertise.

Comment: It is possible to have multiple first authors, at least in some venues.  Did your venue recognize A, B and C as first authors?

Comment: It's for a resume in finance. I work in a physics lab and have a couple publications and would like to list them. @Kimball I'm not sure. All that is listed is that we contributed equally to the work. Does this count as first authorship?

Comment: Another option is "co-first authored a paper", as these are sometimes referred to *co-first authors*.

Answer (score 4):

**If your resume has a text statement about this work, describe your contribution, not your authorship position.**

The point of author ordering is to give a rough guide of level of contribution.  But if you are actually describing the work in words, you can do better than that: give specifics that highlight the importance of your role.  Examples:

> Was the primary person responsible for developing algorithm X.
>
> Designed and executed experiments showing Y.
>
> Conceived of the original idea for the work and contributed to experimental design and statistical analysis.

This is much better information about what you did.

If in some context you need a way to describe your authorship position in words, you could call yourself:

> Co-first author (along with A and C).

You would need to mention A and C so that it is clear you are one of three, not one of two.

However, I'm not convinced that people will give you much credit for being one of three "first" authors.  I probably wouldn't bother to mention it.

Comment: Go into 'text' discussion of who did what if it is important. But never rearrange author order when listing the paper. If author order matters to your audience - then anything you do to try to 'manipulate' what they see such as coyly writing 'I coauthored with these people' just raises red flags.